# How can I create a "base" for other aliases to refer to and enable cd base/x command directories?

Tags: bash, alias, cd-command

I have `.bash_aliases` with:

```
alias c1='cd /home/me/code/php'
alias c2='cd /home/me/code/jquery'
alias c3='cd /home/me/code/ruby'
alias c4='cd /home/me/code/c'
```

How can I [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) this up and loosen the coupling to that entire directory structure?

I have tried:

```
alias code_base='/home/me/code/'
alias c1='cd code_base/php'
alias c2='cd code_base/jquery'
alias c3='cd code_base/ruby'
alias c4='cd code_base/c'
```

but I get the error 'is a directory' when I try and use `c1` through `c4`.

I also tried:

```
alias c1='cd `code_base`/php'
```

but that didn't work; it gave me:

> bash: cd: /php: No such file or directory

I tried `alias c1='cd '+`work`+'/php'`, but that gave me the directory error too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather use a variable to define the base directory.

```
CODE_BASE="/home/me/code/"
alias c1="cd $CODE_BASE/php"
alias c2="cd $CODE_BASE/jquery"
alias c3="cd $CODE_BASE/ruby"
alias c4="cd $CODE_BASE/c"
```

Comment: Note make sure to use `"`'s and not `'`'s

Comment: @MichaelDurrant You can't use `'` here, because $CODE_BASE variable is used inside alias and `'` won't let expand this variable. In general case, you can use either `'` either `"`. Both work well.

Comment: Single quotes are fine;  substitution of the variable  is just delayed until the alias is executed.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the answer from mgorven you can also use the `CDPATH` variable. From [man bash](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=bash&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en):

```
   CDPATH The  search  path for the cd command.  This is a colon-separated
          list of directories in which the  shell  looks  for  destination
          directories  specified  by  the  cd  command.  A sample value is
          ".:~:/usr".
```

If you'd set it to `CDPATH=.:$HOME/code/` you can just run `cd php` and would change the directory to `$HOME/code/php` if the directory exists.

Another solution is to use hashed directories if you are using `zsh`, e.g:

```
hash -d code_base=/home/me/code/
```

Afterwards you can use `cd ~code_base/directory` to change to a specific directory.